# Cannot implicitly convert type error

Tags: c#, 3-tier

I have subjected error. Why this error is comming, even I used same thing for my other classes.

```
ActCtrl ctrl = new ActCtrl();
Act action = ctrl.GetAct(companyID, actionID);
```

And in Act class.

```
public Act GetAct(string companyID, string actionID)
{
    return (new ActBO()).GetAct(companyID, actionID);
}
```

And in BO class

```
public Act GetAct(string companyID, string actionID)
{
return (new ActDAO()).GetAct(companyID, actionID);
}
```

It gives me Cannot implicitly convert type 'Ent.Act' to 'ERP.Actions.Act' error on

```
Act action = ctrl.GetAct(companyID, actionID);
```

Any idea please. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have two classes called `Act` defined in different namespaces? One in `Ent` and one in `ERP.Actions`? Seems tha this is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two different `Act` classes - one in the `Ent` namespace, and one in `ERP.Actions.Act`.

Your `action` variable is of type `ERP.Actions.Act`, but `ctrl.GetAct` is returning an `Ent.Act` reference.

It's not clear what these classes are meant to be, but you may well want to try to collapse them to *one* class - or at least rename one of them for clarity.

Comment: Yes I resolved the issue. It was mixing with an .aspx form. Thanks